# Record and playback audio using Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms

I'm currently developing functionality to record and save audio within a Xamarin Forms application.

I have seen a few examples but none really cover Xamarin Forms.

The closest match I've seen and tried to implement is:

https://github.com/jcphlux/XamarinAudioManager

But this example does not record, only playback. Is there a simple example or way I can add on this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this example, you will also need to install the nugest package and make sure you are using profile111 in your project.:

https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder/